# id, class и role к элементу

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Много раз вижу где используют вот такой вид записи

```
<main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
```

Когда спрашивал у специалистов, то все в один голос твердят, что `id` лучше не использовать и `role` тоже не нужен.

В этом примере задействовано всё. Почему авторы таких записей не используют лишь `class`?

В каких случаях такой формат будет правильным или более удобным?

Comment: [применимость атрибута `role`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/PF/XTech/HTML5/RoleAttribute): accessibility,
device adaptation,
server-side processing, and
complex data description.

Comment: всё зависит от контекста конкретного элемента. например, id может быть использован для якоря, а role перекочевал из xhtml с целью улучшить семантику кода.

Comment: если указан тег html5 - зачем тогда еще задавать role для этого тега, может в этом случае не использовать role

Comment: http://css-live.ru/articles/default-implicit-aria-semantics.html

Answer (score 4):

У каждого атрибута свое назначение, поэтому нельзя уверенно говорить, стоит их использовать или нет.

Элемент с атрибутом id является уникальным на странице.
id используются для работы с JS.
Например не стоит указывать id="header", если в дальнейшем с элементом не будет осуществляться JS манипуляций.

Атрибут class предназначен для описания стилей элемента. Также можно обращаться к элементу с помощью JS по селектору класса, но желательно в большинстве случаев использовать для этих целей атрибут data-role, тем самым изолировать от классов работу JS и повысить читаемость кода. С помощью data-role указывается поведение/назначение элемента, например data-role="slider", data-role="modal", data-role="button" и т.д.

Атрибут role изначально является семантическим.
Возможные значения описаны в [спецификации](https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab#XHTMLRoleVocabulary)