# HTML-атрибут role

Tags: html, атрибуты

Для чего используется HTML-атрибут `role`? Для кого он указывается? Является ли он обязательным для HTML-элементов?

**P. S.** Вопрос «[id, class и role к элементу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/478830/208074)» отвечает только на треть моего вопроса.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [id, class и role к элементу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478830/id-class-%d0%b8-role-%d0%ba-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%83)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Данный атрибут используется для [семантических тегов](https://html5book.ru/html5-semantic-elements/), которых появилось большое множество в **HTML5**.

Атрибут `role`, позволяет наиболее четко указать назначение блока/элемента страницы при взаимодействии пользователя с сайтом.

Данный атрибут - не обязательный и по большей части формальный.

**Основные и наиболее часто используемые значения role:**

- `banner` - содержит главный заголовок или внутренний заголовок страницы. Например логотип и название сайта. Рекомендуется использовать не больше одного раза на странице.
- `complementary` - информационный блок, отделенный от основного содержания ресурса.
- `contentinfo` - обобщающая информация о содержании страницы ( к примеру футер сайта ). Рекомендуется использовать не больше одного раза на странице.
- `definition` - указывает определение термина или понятия.
- `main` - выступает в качестве основного содержания документа. Рекомендуется использовать не больше одного раза на странице.
- `navigation` - набор элементов предназначенных для навигации по документу или связанным документам. Рекомендуется использовать не больше одного раза на странице.
- `note` - заметка ( вспомогательная информация) к основному содержанию ресурса.
- `search` - указывает область для поиска по содержимому.

Answer (score 8):

Атрибут `role` с соответствующими значениями используется программами экранного доступа через речевой или тактильный вывод информации. Он задается не только для семантических элементов. Полный перечень значений для всех html-элементов вы можете найти на сайте [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#docconformance)